# which format is best for upload video & audio

Tags: ios

I am working on "upload video & audio to server",I want to know which format is best for upload (consider the quality & file-size)

Comment: Normal HTTP or HTTPS with multi-part.

Answer (score 1):

video formats are just containers, if you want to consider quality and file size you should look into the encoding of video. For ios based devices h264 encoder with high efficiency level 4 provides the good compression, hence you will get good quality in less file size.
If you want to learn about conversion of video data from one format to another please look into [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/).